# Determine if it's a static IP or a DHCP IP

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, dhcp

I'm trying to find a genric solution across all linux distro to find if the *IP* address attached to the system is a *static* or a *DHCP* ?

On ubuntu , I can find if it's *static* or *DHCP* by doing a *DHCP* grep on `/var/log/syslog` but it is not generic solution , it might differ on other platforms.

One of the target board is *Cortina* and I'm using open *wrt* as a boot up kernel for that. There is no `var/log/syslog` on *Cortina* nothing similar to that also.

Comment: If you `ifconfig <your_interface>` and look at the flags listed, you may be able to find "DHCP" - this may be a little more generic across distros

Comment: @BigChris ifconfig interface doesn't display anything about the type of connection :/

Comment: In that case there's no method universal across all linux distros. There is a syslog on openwrt though which will tell you this though. It's just not a file.

Comment: I only did a quick look up and came across this resource: http://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/137682-how-tell-if-i-am-using-dhcp-static.html

Answer (score 6):

You have the command in `nmcli`.
This should work in all Linux flavors, I believe:

```
nmcli -f ipv4.method con show eno16780032
```

If the output is `auto`, then it is DHCP.
If the output is `manual`, then it is static.

Comment: I get  “Error: ‘con’ command ‘show’ is not valid.”

Comment: Use `-g` instead of `-f` for batch-friendly.

Answer (score 5):

```
ip a | grep dynamic
```

If output is nothing -> your IP address is statically assigned.

If output is a line with `dynamic` in it -> your IP address is dynamically/dhcp assigned.

If the IP address is assigned by dhcp your line should be something like this:

```
inet 192.168.1.5/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s3
```

Tested on Debian and Rocky Linux (CentOS)...

Answer (score 4):

If its CentOS, you can check /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0. Check **BOOTPROTO** entry says. If its **dhcp** then its DHCP configured. If its **Static** or **none**, then its not **DHCP**

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, if you're using NetworkManager, for example, it's going to be requesting an IP and gateway and DNS server. But beyond that, once it's got the information it needs, it sets addressing information essentially statically. Essentially, the rest of your machine doesn't know or care if an address is static or dynamic, just that it has an address.

You can check `/var/log/syslog` for DHCPACK entries specifically. I believe dhclient and NetworkManager write there.

Answer (score 2):

Type in terminal

> cat /etc/network/interfaces

You should find one of this lines

> iface eth0 inet dhcp

that means that IP for interface eth0 is from DHCP

> iface eth0 inet static

Above line shows that IP is static. You should also find other parameters.

Comment: What does it mean if the result is `iface lo inet loopback`?

Comment: cat: /etc/network/interfaces: No such file or directory ON Fedora 29

Answer (score 0):

In my testing in 2023, this works in multiple versions of CentOS/Rocky/RedHat/SuSE and Ubuntu:

```shell
# These are inverse of each other:
ip route list default | grep dhcp
ip route list default | grep static
```

**Note**: `ip` command is provided by `iproute` or `iproute2` package, depending on the distribution.

#### Static IP command output:

```shell
$ ip route list default
default via X.X.X.X dev ens160 proto static metric 100
```

#### DHCP command output:

```shell
$ ip route list default
default via X.X.X.X dev ens192 proto dhcp src Y.Y.Y.Y metric 100
```

#### Bash Example

```shell
if ip route list default | grep dhcp > /dev/null ; then 
   Do Something on DHCP machines
fi
```

[credit](https://superuser.com/questions/955790/determine-if-its-a-static-ip-or-a-dhcp-ip)

#### Extra credit: Puppet Integration

Puppet fact example:

```ruby
Facter.add("is_dhcp") do
  setcode do
    route = Puppet::Util::Execution.execute(['ip route list default'], :failonfail => false)
    result = route ? "#{route}".match?(/dhcp/) : false
  end
end
```

Comment: how did you test this on ubuntu? it outputs `dynamic`, not `dhcp`

Comment: @BЈовић can you clarify which part of my answer you are referring to? I checked that `ip route list default` includes `dhcp` on Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 (I currently only have LTS available to test)